# Error123: The element type "application" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</application>"

Tags: android, android-manifest

there are some serious problems with my Androidmanifest.xml file. I am getting the error message in the title, except the "123". I have read the other questions, but all of the solutions they suggested haven't fixed my problem. I know I am overlooking something though. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.tiarnan.tinder">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

    <activity android:name=".ChooseLoginOrRegistrationActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<application>
    </activit android:name="com.example.tiarnan.tinder.RegistrationActivity"></activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: By the way, `</activit android:name="com.example.tiarnan.tinder.RegistrationActivity"></activity>` - **activit**y is misspelled.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems on that manifest file:

- The XML file is not well formed, as you haven't closed the first activity tag, it should be:

  `<activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>`
- An android manifest file can only have **one** manifest tag with **one** application tag inside, but for some reason you're adding another manifest tag after it has been closed, you should get rid of that.

Your manifest file would look like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tiarnan.tinder">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

        <activity android:name=".ChooseLoginOrRegistrationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It works perfectly. I guess I must have messed around in it too much, when trying to fix the problem. But thank you so much.